# Difference between { } and '{ }

Tags: operators, system-verilog

What's the difference between these two operator? (In System Verilog).
I know that { } is the bit squeezing operator but i wonder if there is difference with '{ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, there is a difference.

The first one `{}` means concatenation. It results in a vector that consists of bits of its operands. It is used in generic verilog operations.

The second one `'{}` is a definition of a anonymous aggregate structure such as an array or struct. It is used in aggregate/pattern assignments. It also has a set of features to do pattern expression to assign to specified members of structs and arrays.

In case of packed arrays and structs and without pattern expressions both operators behave similarly.